# How to solve differential equation with multiple data for the parameters by using text file in python?

Tags: python

I am just learning programming. I solved 2nd order differential equation in python with constant parameters but I want to solve the equation with multiple data for the parameters from text file. I have more than 1000 different values in the text file for all Ex, Ey and Ez. Ex, Ey and Ez are the function of x, y and z. How to solve the differential equation with all the values? I want single plot (trajectory) at the end. Here is my code:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

m = 9.1 *(10)**(-31)    
q = 1.6 *(10)**(-19)    
Bx = 0.00942 *(10)**(-4)
By = 0.46264 *(10)**(-4)
Bz = 0.1825 *(10)**(-4)





with open("field_x.txt") as f:
    flines = f.readlines()
    Ex = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines] #Ex = 1.579, 3.456, 16.25, 68.99,.....

with open("field_y.txt") as f:
    flines = f.readlines()
    Ey = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines]  #Ey = 25.793, 23.14, 14.25, 16.25,......

with open("field_z.txt") as f:
    flines = f.readlines()
    Ez = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines]#Ez = -102457.243, 2003.56, 21134.89,210.35,...

#Position x,y,z
with open("position_x.txt") as f:
    flines = f.readlines()
    x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines] #x=0.1, 0.3, 0.5,...

with open("position_y.txt") as f:
    flines = f.readlines()
    y = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines] #y= 0.0, 0.5, 0.6,...

with open("position_z.txt") as f:
    flines = f.readlines()
    z = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in flines] #z=0.1, 0.5, 0.64


#array for field components
Ex1 = np.array(Ex)
Ey1 = np.array(Ey)
Ez1 = np.array(Ez)



#array for position
xs = np.array(x) 
ys = np.array(y)
zs = np.array(z)

#linear interpolation of Ex1, Ey1, Ez1
Exf = LinearNDInterpolator((xs, ys, zs), Ex1)
Eyf = LinearNDInterpolator((xs, ys, zs), Ey1)
Ezf = LinearNDInterpolator((xs, ys, zs), Ez1)

#array of new point
x1 = np.linspace(0, 5, 10)
y1 = np.linspace(0, 7, 10)
z1 = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

#creating array([x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],....) for new grids
X = np.dstack((x1,y1,z1))
points = np.array(X)

#Field at new grids after linear interpolation
fEx = Exf(points)
fEy = Eyf(points)
fEz = Ezf(points)

def trajectory(w, t, p):

    x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3 = w
    q, m, fEx, fEy, fEz, Bx, By, Bz = p


    f = [y1, q*(fEx + y2 * Bz - y3 * By) / m, y2, q*(fEy - y1 * Bz + y3 * Bx) / m, y3, q*(fEz + y1 * By - y2 * Bx) / m] 

#initial condition
x1 = 0.0
y1 = 0.0
x2 = 0.0
y2 = 0.0
x3 = 0.006
y3 = 691762.096

#time
t = np.arange(0*(10)**(-9), 10.0*(10)**(-9), 0.01*(10)**(-9))


p = [q, m, fEx, fEy, fEz, Bx, By, Bz]
w0 = [x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3]

#SOlving the equation
wsol = odeint(trajectory, w0, t, args=(p,))

#output data
X = wsol[:,0]      
Y = wsol[:,2]      
Z = wsol[:,4]      

#plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(t,X,  color= 'b', label=('x'))
ax.plot(t,Y, color= 'r', label=('y'))
ax.plot(t,Z, color= 'c', label=('z'))
ax.set_xlabel('Time(ns)')
ax.set_ylabel('position(m)')
plt.show()
```

I am not getting the right output from this solution. I am expecting single plot at the end.

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure I understand: you already have a working solution for any given set of Ex, Ey, Ez - and you just want to know how to extract the 1000s of values from the text files, set them up in a `[(Ex1,Ey1,Ez1),(Ex2,Ey2,Ez2),...]` structure so that you can make a plot for each set of values?
In that case, you may need to show what the text files look like - are they just a list of values?

Comment: Sorry! Here, I solved the equation for single value of Ex, Ey and Ez. I want to solve the equation with multiple value of Ex, Ey and Ez. I have list of 1000 values in the text file  for Ex, Ey and Ez.  I am expecting single output plot due to the all Ex, Ey and Ez.

Comment: Please explain what is your current output?

Comment: @Ssein I am not getting any output,  I think, the linear interpolation method is not correct. I don't know what's wrong in my code! When I use a single value of Ex, Ey and Ez, I am getting right output but not for multiple values.

Comment: @Ssein  I found 1 link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860451/odeint-with-multiple-parameters-time-dependent here Warren Weckesser is answered but in my problem, I am not getting output.

Comment: When you get your output from Ex, Ey and Ez and with the rest of your code not, means that you are not passing a list of 1000 samples to your plot. So my suggestion is split up your code to different parts. Make sure #output data
`X = wsol[:,0],      
Y = wsol[:,2],      
Z = wsol[:,4] ` are lists of samples(like your Ex, Ey and Ez)

Comment: @Ssein I think it's due to the 3D interpolation problem if I have the right value of fEx, fEy and fEz after interpolation then I will get the output. Would you please check my code for interpolation and give me some hints.

Comment: Not sure, but I you could make a function for your linear interpolation like `fEx = interpn(xs, ys, zs)` and then pass `Ex1`,.. as argument like `fEx(Ex1)`